# Help with date list validation and blank fields

Tags: 2013, validation-list-items

New to Sharepoint trying to find my way:)

I have the following structure :
StartDate1,EndDate1,StartDate2,EndDate2
StartDate1 and EndDate1 are mandatory fields.
StartDate2 and EndDate2 are not.
I’m trying to create a list validation where if Start date 2
contains data EndDate2 cannot left Blank (and vice verca) and at the same time for both Start End Date columns , End dates are not earlier than Start Dates

Any assistance will be highly appreciated 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you have four columns `StartDate1`, `StartDate2`, `EndDate1`, and `EndDate2`. I'll shorten these to `S1`, `S2`, `E1`, and `E2`respectively. **The final equation will use the full names at the bottom of the post.** If the validation doesn't work, please let me know.

> To put list validation on, you have to go to **List Settings** > **Validation Settings** as per this image below. Column validation doesn't allow for multi-column validation, AFAIK.
>
> [image]

`S1` and `E1` are always required.

`S2` and `E2` are only occasionally required. If one is filled out, the other must also be filled.

`Sn` and `En` must be in chronological order (ie `S1 < E1`)

For this we can take `S1` and `E1` and mark them required in the column definition to save some additional logic in the item validation.

List validation triggers when an expression equates to `FALSE`.

To check if an item is greater than we can ask `S1 < E1 AND S2 < E2` If those both hold up, we get a true return. If not, we get a false return. In SharePoint this turns into

```
=AND(StartDate1 < EndDate1, StartDate2 < EndDate2)
```

Now we also need the conditionally required columns, `S2` and `E2`. Check out the table below. We want to evaluate to `FALSE`.

```
S2 Present | E2 Present || Valid?
---------------------------------
     F     |     F      ||   T
     F     |     T      ||   F
     T     |     F      ||   F
     T     |     T      ||   T
```

We need a `TRUE` for both empty, and a `TRUE` for both full to get the proper `FALSE` values. So if we have `(S2 AND E2) OR (NOT S2 AND NOT E2)` we'd get...

```
=OR(
   NOT(
      AND(
         ISBLANK(StartDate2),
         ISBLANK(EndDate2)
      )
   ),
   AND(
      ISBLANK(StartDate2),
      ISBLANK(EndDate2)
   )
)
```

Now we need both conditions to be `TRUE` in order to pass the validation, so that implies an AND condition. We can add the bottom, longer, condition to the previous AND condition. The final validation string should be:

```
=AND(
   StartDate1 < EndDate1, 
   StartDate2 < EndDate2,
   OR(
      AND(
         NOT(ISBLANK(StartDate2)),
         NOT(ISBLANK(EndDate2))
      ),
      AND(
         ISBLANK(StartDate2),
         ISBLANK(EndDate2)
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply KGlacier as well as for the logic explained.Unfortunately When S2 is blank and only E2 has value , validation passes. Please check again if possible.Thanks again.

Comment: @LoukasTS Sorry, I put the NOT operator at the wrong spot. Please try again. I’ll update the description in the morning.

Comment: KGlasier, works perfect as it should be!!Thanks for helping

Comment: Great! Don’t forget to mark it as an answer so others know :) @LoukasTS